# Is there any gnome-shell mixer icon relying on alsa and not pulseaudio?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome3, alsa, gnome-shell, pulseaudio

So, long story short, when I installed Mint 12 on my Dell laptop I realized my HDA-intel sound board have problems with pulseaudio. I uninstalled pulseaudio and got my sound back, but removing pulseaudio also removes that nice little mixer icon on the top panel of gnome-shell, and messes up with the sound configuration app.

Is there any other solution to just removing pulseaudio? I also tried just killing it, but the same thing happens.

If not, is there any gnome-shell extension that will create a similar icon based on alsa and not on pulseaudio (the old mixer from Gnome2 would be great).

The longer story can be read [Problems with sound with HDA-Intel on Mint 12](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=88747)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [volwheel](http://oliwer.net/b/volwheel.html).

> VolWheel is a little application which lets you control the sound volume easily through a tray icon you can scroll on. It is written in Perl/Gtk2 and works both for ALSA and OSS. You can configure it quickly through its configuration interface.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [alsa mixer](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/518/alsa-mixer/) extension gnome extension.

Just going there and clicking "on" should install the icon

Comment: Could you explain briefly how this link solves the problem for OP.

Comment: That link provides the gnome extension that will create the volume icon. Just going there and clicking "on" should install the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I have HDA intel sound on my gigabyte mobo and use **alsamixer** with archlinux

Answer (score 0):

You could use volumeicon: http://softwarebakery.com/maato/volumeicon.html

> Volume Icon aims to be a lightweight volume control that sits in your
>   systray.
>
> ```
> Change volume by scrolling on the systray icon
> Ability to choose which channel to control
> Several icon themes (with gtk theme as default)
> Configurable external mixer
> Volume Slider
> Hotkey support
> ```

As I checked it already uses GTK3 and depends only on alsa, uses notifications, so runing in gnome-shell should be no problem.